# can someone tell me why this while loop is not working?

Tags: c#

```cs
Random rnd = new Random();
Random rnd1 = new Random();
int number = rnd.Next(0, 6);
int number1 = rnd1.Next(0, 6);

while (number == number1) // I want my while loop to stop only when 2 number are not equal and then print
{
    if (number != number1 && number > number1)
    {

    }
    else if (number != number1 && number < number1)
    {
    }

    break;
}
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "doesn't work"? Did you debug that and examined if the loop is reached?

Comment: 1. You're not generating new random numbers inside the loop, so the values always remain whatever they are at the beginning. 2. You're calling `break;` on every iteration, regardless of conditions, so it will only ever iterate 0 or 1 times (0 if the numbers don't match from the beginning). 3. If you're using .NET Framework, `rnd` and `rnd1` have an incredibly high potential to be using the same seed, meaning they will generate the same random numbers as each other. Regardless, you only need a single `Random` instance here.

Comment: Also, the `number != number1` condition is pointless when you AND it with a condition that tests the same thing in a more restrictive manner (in other words, since the first condition will always be true if the second condition is true, then you don't need the first condition)

Answer (score 4):

1. You have the "break" statement inside, which means it always exits the loop after the first iteration.
2. You generate random numbers, and if those numbers are the same, it enters the loop, but you don't change the numbers inside the loop, which means the loop never ends.

Solution:
Remove the "break;" and generate new random numbers for number and number1 inside the loop

So it looks something like this

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int number = rnd.Next(0, 6);
int number1 = rnd.Next(0, 6);

while (number == number1) // I want my while loop to stop only when 2 number are not equal and then print
{
    number = rnd.Next(0, 6);
    number1 = rnd.Next(0, 6);
    if (number != number1 && number > number1)
    {

    }
    else if (number != number1 && number < number1)
    {

    }
}
```